# How Get Spooled File list separately from it's format - Java ( JT400 )

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

#### I get Spooled list to java using jt400. but i want to get Advanced Spooled file( *.TIFF image formatted Spooled files) list and normal Spooled (Can read Text) file list separately. Anyone know how to do that ?

#### Thanks in Advance!

```
                    try{
      


         AS400 server = new AS400();
        System.out.println(" Now receiving all spooled files Synchronously");

        SpooledFileList splfList = new SpooledFileList( server );

        // set filters, all users, on all queues
        splfList.setUserFilter("user");
        splfList.setQueueFilter("/QSYS.LIB/%ALL%.LIB/%ALL%.OUTQ");



        // open list, openSynchronously() returns when the list is completed.
        splfList.openSynchronously();
       // Enumeration enum = splfList.getObjects();
        Enumeration enumx = splfList.getObjects();

        while(enumx.hasMoreElements())
        {
            SpooledFile splf = (SpooledFile)enumx.nextElement();
        
            if ( splf != null )
            {
                
               String Name = splf.getName();
               int Number = splf.getNumber();
               String jobname = splf.getJobName();
               String jobuser = splf.getJobUser();
               String jobnumber = splf.getJobNumber();
              //  strSpooledNumber = splf.getStringAttribute(SpooledFile.)
                System.out.println(" spooled file = Name :" + Name + " number : " + Number + " JobName : " + jobname + " job user : " + jobuser + " job Number : " + jobnumber);
            }
        }
        // clean up after we are done with the list
        splfList.close();
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
       
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing class doesn't have a filter on printer device type, although you could add one using getUserFilter as an example.

Once you have the full list of spooled files, you could split them yourself into two groups.  Try `String prtdevtype = splf.getStringAttribute(ATTR_PRTDEVTYPE);`

From this you can tell if you have a text spooled file (*SCS) or one with graphics in it (*IPDS, *AFPDS).

Comment: @ buck , Thanks buck i got it :D . can you tell me *IPDS is what ? and *AFPDS is what ? i mean if *SCS = text, then *IPDS and *AFPDS ??? *TIFF OR *GIF or what ?? Thank you

Comment: If you really have TIFF data in a spooled file, the device type is probably *USERASCII.

Comment: buck , ok then *USERASCII = TIFF format . can you tell me this file types mean *IPDS, *AFPDS ??

Comment: Intelligent Printer Data Stream and Advanced Function Print Data Stream.  These both hold graphics generated on the IBM machine.  The [Printing V Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg242160.html) has some information on these types of printers.